# varnish purging showing error 403 Not allowed

Tags: varnish

In varnish configuration file I put my public address inside acl. Still I can not purge varnish cache. It shows 403 error. I want to purge varnish remotely.I want to purge varnish only from my IP. Please help me how I can set the acl.

Comment: What is your complete VCL file? Do you use SSL termination (via Nginx)?

Comment: I am not using ssl. I am using cloudflare. Is varnish getting the IP of cloudflare ?

Comment: Yep. That explains it. You will need to update purge logic to check for ```X-Forwarded-For``` header value to match your IP address.

Comment: How can I do it ?

Comment: Check my answer. Tested with Varnish 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at this tutorial [purging varnish cache remotely](http://cloudkul.com/blog/purge-varnish-cache-remotely-using-cloudflare/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 sub vcl_recv {
     if (req.method == "PURGE") {
         # If not allowed then a error 405 is returned
         if (! req.http.x-forwarded-for || req.http.x-forwarded-for !~ "1.2.3.4") {
            return(synth(405, "This forwarded IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests."));
        }
        return (purge);
    }
}
```